Thunderbird Cal/Card-DAV autoconfiguration with Radicale and nginx reverse proxy
I'm running Radicale Cal/Card-DAV server with nginx as reverse proxy.
Authentication in Radicale is via htpasswd/bcrypt.
This is the snippet from my nginx config:
location /radicale/ { # The trailing / is important!
    proxy_pass        http://[::1]:5232/; # The / is important!
    proxy_set_header  X-Script-Name /radicale;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    }

I think I need to rewrite $remote_user for Thunderbird DAV autoconfiguration; TB sends my  whole email address as username, while I would like to only have the %EMAILLOCALPART%, like it happens for SMTP/IMAP auto-configuration.
I tried using the map directive but failed so many times.
I believe the regexp is alright but there's something else not working because in radicale's log I always see 'HTTP_REMOTE_USER': 'emailaddress', no matter what.
    map $remote_user $localpart {
        default $remote_user;
        ~^(\w+)\@domain.+$ $1;
    }

I wouldn't know how to pass that $localpart to the location and I'm stuck.
What I was able to do is to generate the htpasswd string using whole email address as username and TB autoconfiguration worked, so I know it's just a matter of "rewriting" $remote_user, or at least that's what I believe.

To achieve what you're trying to do with Nginx, you need to extract the local part of the email and then use it as the REMOTE_USER header. Here's how you can modify your Nginx configuration to achieve this:

Use a regex map to extract the local part of the email address.
Pass this mapped value to the REMOTE_USER header.

Here is the updated configuration for your Nginx setup:
# Define a map to extract the local part of the email
map $remote_user $localpart {
    default $remote_user;
    ~^([^@]+)@.*$ $1;
}

server {
    location /radicale/ {
        proxy_pass http://[::1]:5232/; # The / is important!
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /radicale;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $localpart; # Use the mapped local part here
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    }
}

In this configuration:

The map directive creates a variable $localpart that extracts the local part of the email address using a regex pattern.
The proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $localpart; sets the REMOTE_USER header to the local part of the email address.

This way, Nginx will pass the local part of the email address as the REMOTE_USER to the backend.
Make sure to reload or restart Nginx after making these changes to apply the new configuration.

Thank you, been working on this all day and from logs now I'm getting the localpart correctly, but for whatever reason, the last log from Radicale still tells it wants to auth using email: Jul 11 13:44:41 pandora.example.tld radicale[3547549]: [2024-07-11 13:44:41 +0200] [3547549/Thread-18 (process_request_thread)] [WARNING] Failed login attempt from ::1 (forwarded for 'IP-Redacted'): 'roughnecks@example.tld'

Adding the link to the issue I opened on Radicale: https://github.com/Kozea/Radicale/issues/1536

One other thing, sorry. I think the default $remote_user; line must be the last one in map
